# Subscribe to information output to screen by Gmapping?

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping-demo, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to subscribe to the information output to the screen by Gmapping? It prints out a lot more information that it allows subscriptions to or services for. I want to be able to get that information without modifying the Gmapping code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39249/subscribe-to-information-output-to-screen-by-gmapping?/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-19**:
In which datum specifically are you interested?

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-19**:
Specifically, I'm interested in the Average Scan Matching Score and the Scan Matching Failed alert.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-19**:
I'm unfamiliar with how to open the output in a pipe....

EDIT: After reading about ROS launch output, (either output to "screen" or "log") piping does seem to be the ONLY way. Thanks for the advice

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-19**:
@dornhege was right. I was able to pipe it into a simple publisher I wrote. Thanks. I am now opening up a new Question to see if I can add pipes to roslaunch xml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC gmapping does not use ROS_... output, so it is not possible by a ROS way. You could still open the output in a pipe or something like that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1